# multiple filters in one appender

Tags: logging, logback

Can I configure multiple log filters under one appender in my logback.xml?

I tried creating as below, but this is not working. Is there a way to make it work?

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<filter class="FilterClass1">
</filter>

<filter class="FilterClass2">
</filter>
</appender>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

adding to Najme's answer, in logback.xml terms

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <filter class="FilterClass1">
  <onMatch>NEUTRAL</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>          


<filter class="FilterClass2">
  <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
  <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
</filter>
</appender>
```

The first filter should onMatch(), be set to NEUTRAL and consequent filters...
Only the final filter should onMatch() be set to ACCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

in first filter calss set for matching: FilterReply.NEUTRAL

```
    public class FirstFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Object eventObject) {
        LoggingEvent event = (LoggingEvent) eventObject;
        if (event.getMessage() != null && event.getMessage().contains("sampel")) {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        } else {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
    }
}
```

and in second filter class set FilterReply.ACCEPT

```
public class SecondFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Object event) {
        LoggingEvent event1 = (LoggingEvent) event;
        if (event1.getMessage() != null && event1.getMessage().contains("sample2")) {
            return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
        } else {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
    }
}
```